# Using Visual Studio 2010 with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2010

Do I need to upgrade Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012 in order to develop on SharePoint 2013?

Is the new SharePoint 2013 designer plug-in compatible with Visual Studio 2010?

Are any features locked out of SharePoint 2013 if I stick to using Visual Studio 2010? Does work with SharePoint 2013, do I lose any functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work without upgrading VS2010

take a look at this link which states the Requirement for SP 2013

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30722

Comment: it is SharePoint 2013 SDK (SharePoint2013SDK.msi) with 230Mb size

Comment: it has lots unneeded of extra stuff

Answer (score 3):

Most of your SP2013-specific development will be Apps, so you'll be better off installing VS 2012. Also, the project templates for lists etc is hugely improved in VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Visual Studio 2010 will work with SharePoint 2013 but you'll miss out on the new SharePoint 2013-specific templates, for example anything related to the new App Model.

Answer (score 2):

although the question is about VS 2010 but i was redirected here when i was looking for VS 2012 solution and the following is description of the solution which works for me.

you can install **Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012** through [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) or use the [offline installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=279063&clcid=0x409) with size of **36mb**.

a new category called **Office/SharePoint** is created which have all the sharepoint 2010 & 2013 templates available, besides office and new SharePoint App Model

[image]

http://zimmergren.net/technical/upgrading-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions-to-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 1):

I googled to use VS 2010 for SP2013 but no luck. Finally intsalled VS 2012 and follow below link:

http://yalla.itgroove.net/2012/08/sharepoint-2013-project-templates-for-visual-studio-2012/

Thanks,
Nirnajan

Answer (score 1):

I would have make a statement on SigarDave post but I don't have enough reputation. Hence this answer, so please be comprehensive :)

I've tested to load samples projects from the Sharepoint 2013 SDk as SigarDave linked into my VS2010. I just wanted to outline here that some examples will not work and display an incompatibility message between the project and your VS version, mostly when the project concerning Sharepoint app's which is not handled into VS2010. And when you don't have this error, you have to download some unknown dependencies ...

So hold tight your mental health if you mind to develop Sharepoint 2013 solutions with VS2010